# Mysql 2 queries in one?

Tags: sql, mysql

Apparently i need two queries to get the data i need. I cant give out to much information but is it possible to write 2 queries in one statement? (I have a feeling it is possible).

Using mysql 4

Comment: Did you forget your actual specific question?

Comment: Yes, but you need to give more information I feel for anyone to be able to help you in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tooVague;
SELECT * FROM googleIt;
```

Comment: lol :). I Thought left join may have to do with it but this is simple :) +1 and answered.

Comment: And this is one statement? ;-)

Comment: If you're using the Connector/J JDBC driver, you have to give it permission to run multiple queries in a single request.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Scroll down to Security > allowMultiQueries.

Comment: Link for MySQL 4:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Answer (score -1):

If the question is "Can I execute two commands in one query?" then the answer is "no."

Comment: Any reason this was downvoted? If you're going to downvote, at least tell me how I'm wrong.

Comment: I didnt do it but i assume the answer is yes and no is wrong?